# Triple integral formula

Tags: calculus

Prove that this formula stands for all $f(x)$ that are integrateable in $[0,a]$
$$\int_0^a \int_0^z \int_0^y f(x)dxdydz=\frac12 \int_0^a (a-x)^2 f(x)dx$$

How exactly should I change the order of integration here? hints?

Answer (score 1):

The region of integration is $0 \leq x \leq y \leq z \leq a$.  So, for a fixed value of $x$, the region of integration for $y$ and $z$ becomes $\mathscr{R} : x \leq y \leq z \leq a$.  And
$$
\iint_{\mathscr{R}} dA_{yz} = \int_x^a \int_x^z dy \,\, dz = \int_x^a (z - x) \,\, dz = \int_0^{a-x} z' \,\, dz' = \frac{1}{2} (a - x)^2.
$$